# Find which lines in a file contain certain characters

Tags: python, string, search

Is there a way to find out if a string contains any one of the characters in a set with python?

It's straightforward to do it with a single character, but I need to check and see if a string contains any one of a set of bad characters.

Specifically, suppose I have a string:

```
s = 'amanaplanacanalpanama~012345'
```

and I want to see if the string contains any vowels:

```
bad_chars = 'aeiou'
```

and do this in a for loop for each line in a file:

```
if [any one or more of the bad_chars] in s:
    do something
```

I am scanning a large file so if there is a faster method to this, that would be ideal. Also, not every bad character has to be checked---so long as one is encountered that is enough to end the search.

I'm not sure if there is a builtin function or easy way to implement this, but I haven't come across anything yet. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: You may wish to consider changing the title to "find which lines in a file contain certain characters".

Comment: I've changed the title to be more specific, per your suggestion. Thanks! The previous title was very ambiguous and vague.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
any((c in badChars) for c in yourString)
```

or

```
any((c in yourString) for c in badChars)  # extensionally equivalent, slower
```

or

```
set(yourString) & set(badChars)  # extensionally equivalent, slower
```

"so long as one is encountered that is enough to end the search." - This will be true if you use the first method.

You say you are concerned with performance: performance should not be an issue unless you are dealing with a huge amount of data. If you encounter issues, you can try:

---

*Regexes*

**edit** Previously I had written a section here on using regexes, via the `re` module, programatically generating a regex that consisted of a single character-class `[...]` and using `.finditer`, with the caveat that putting a simple backslash before everything might not work correctly. Indeed, after testing it, that is the case, and I would definitely not recommend this method. Using this would require reverse engineering the entire (slightly complex) sub-grammar of regex character classes (e.g. you might have characters like `\` followed by `w`, like `]` or `[`, or like `-`, and merely escaping some like `\w` may give it a new meaning).

---

*Sets*

Depending on whether the `str.__contains__` operation is O(1) or O(N), it may be justifiable to first convert your text/lines into a set to ensure the `in` operation is O(1), if you have many badChars:

```
badCharSet = set(badChars)
any((c in badChars) for c in yourString)
```

(it may be possible to make that a one-liner `any((c in set(yourString)) for c in badChars)`, depending on how smart the python compiler is)

---

*Do you really need to do this line-by-line?*

It may be faster to do this once for the entire file O(#badchars), than once for every line in the file O(#lines*#badchars), though the asymptotic constants may be such that it won't matter.

Answer (score 4):

Use python's `any` function.

```
if any((bad_char in my_string) for bad_char in bad_chars):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be very efficient and clear.  It uses sets:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

bad_chars = set('aeiou')

with open('/etc/passwd', 'r') as file_:
   file_string = file_.read()
file_chars = set(file_string)

if file_chars & bad_chars:
   print('found something bad')
```

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression is twice as fast as `any` with my minimal testing. You should try it with your own data.

```
r = re.compile('[aeiou]')
if r.search(s):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code should print out any character in bad_chars if it exists in s:

```
for i in vowels:
    if i in your charset:
        #do_something
```

You could also use the python in-built any using an example like this:

```
>>> any(e for e in bad_chars if e in s)
True
```